# File Processing to transpose data

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file with IDs and names applicable to them as below:

```
1234|abc|cde|fgh
5678|ijk|abc|lmn
9101|cde|fgh|klm
1213|klm|abc|cde
```

I should get the output as different files having IDs matching each name as below

File1:

```
abc
1234
5678
1213
```

File2:

```
cde
1234
9101
1213
```

File 3:

```
Klm
9101
1213
```

file 4:

```
fgh
1234
9101
```

Comment: Could you use some more words to describe the transformation, and also to put some of those words into the title? "file processing" does not describe what you're doing.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Hi All i guess my edit will make u clear on my ask. requesting for help for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the problem is that for each string present in the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, ..nth field to write a file starting with it and listing the strings from the 1st field of all lines in which it appears:

```
$ awk -F\| '{
   for(i=2; i <= NF; i++){
        if(!a[$i]){ a[$i] = "file_" ++f; print $i > a[$i] }
        print $1 > a[$i];
   }
}'
1234|abc|cde|fgh
5678|ijk|abc|lmn
9101|cde|fgh|klm
1213|klm|abc|cde
^D
$ for f in file_*; do echo === $f ===; cat $f; done
=== file_1 ===
abc
1234
5678
1213
=== file_2 ===
cde
1234
9101
1213
=== file_3 ===
fgh
1234
9101
=== file_4 ===
ijk
5678
=== file_5 ===
lmn
5678
=== file_6 ===
klm
9101
1213
```

Comment: How will i give my file as input to the above awk program?

Comment: Can u pls explain me the above code?

Comment: Pls explain me the above code

Comment: give file as input: `awk -F\| '{` ... `}' yourFile.txt`

Comment: each line of the file will read by `awk` and split with `|` into fields, then for all the fields except for the 1st, a file starting with that field is created if it doesn't already exist, and the 1st field (the ID) is appended to it. An associative array (`a`) is used to keep track of the files that start with a particular field. Notice that in `awk`, `print ".." > file` will not truncate `file`, but will append to it (similar to `>>` in the shell). The created files are named `"file_idx"`, where `idx` will reflect the order in which the corresponding fields were first seen in the input file.

Comment: also, this kind of data re-grouping would've been better demonstrated (without spamming the file system) with something simpler like `awk -F\| '{ for(i=2; i <= NF; i++) a[$i] = a[$i] FS $1 }
END{ for(n in a) print n a[n] }'`

Comment: thank u so much @mosvy.. :)  Also i have one doubt, what if i need the file name to be as the names like.. abc cde and so on instead of file_1 file_2...

Comment: Hi mosvy tried ur second approach.... i actually want to load these id's into table after grouping them for each name. so i guess having them in files will help me further. but have to give a try.

Comment: if you want the names to be like `file_abc`, etc, change `"file_" ++f` to `"file_" $i`; If you want them to be like `abc`, etc, change the body of the loop to `{ if(!a[$i]++) print $i > $i; print $1 > $i  }`; if you want the latter and don't want them to have `abc`, etc on the first line, then use @simohe's answer.

Comment: Getting error **awk: cmd. line:2: (FILENAME=input.csv FNR=1) fatal: can't redirect to `abc' (No such file or directory)** for the new logic to create the file in name of abc instead of file_1

Comment: Getting error awk: cmd. line:2: (FILENAME=input.csv FNR=1) fatal: can't redirect to `file_abc' (No such file or directory) for the new logic to create the file in name of file_abc instead of file_1

Comment: @mosvy cud u pls help on this

Comment: Try making another directory with mkdir, cd into it and then run the script there. I cannot reproduce your error -- it looks like `file_abc` already exists on your machine as a symlink that resolves to a non-existing path.

Comment: used this code ``awk -F\| '{
   for(i=2; i <= NF; i++){
        { if(!a[$i]++) print $i > $i; print $1 > $i };
   }
}' input.csv`` and getting the same error after trying it in new folder also..

Comment: i also observe the first file getting created. error occurs while 2nd file to b e created. In this case abc is getting created. error comes as** awk: cmd. line:2: (FILENAME=input.csv FNR=1) fatal: can't redirect to `cde' (No such file or directory)

Comment: Do yout get the same error when running the unmodified script from the answer?

Comment: maybe the file has embedded nulls (ie it's in utf-16 encoding); what will `hd -n16 input.csv` print?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F '|' '
   {
    for(i = 2; i <= NF; i++)
        print $1 > $i;
    }
' yourFile.txt
```

This scripts writes the 1st column into every file name present in other columns.

details:

- `-F '|'` set field separator to pipe character
- `for(...)` for column 2 until last column
- `print $1 > $i` write the content of column 1 into file with name of column `i`

Comment: The created files are named abc, cde, ... (the id) and do not contain the id as first line.

Comment: ``awk: cmd. line:4: (FILENAME=input.csv FNR=1) fatal: can't redirect to `abc' (No such file or directory)`` i got this error

Comment: Sorry, I can not reproduce the failure. Does the solution of @mosvy fail as well?

Comment: Getting same error again :|

Comment: I see the same error happens for the solution of @mosvy. But here it happens for the 1st file. Can still not reproduce, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you get the ids from.
But assuming you have them somwehere, you can try something like this:

```
for id in abc cde klm fgh; do
    awk -F'|' -v id=$id 'BEGIN{print id} $0 ~ id { print $1; }' test > $id
done
```

Comment: thank u RoVo.. wat if i dono the id list much  before and its not constant.